# Ajax call on submit refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

## Problem

My page seems to be defaulting to my PHP code instead of being handled asynchronously via ajax. As of now, my page just reloads as a blank screen, the input array successfully got passed over to the PHP, which is comforting, but I seem to just be doing something wrong with the ajax.

## What I've tried

After viewing [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099486/jquery-submit-refreshing-page) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803799/submit-with-ajax-refreshing-page), I still cant seem to get this figured out.

## Current Standing

Here is the HTML:

```
    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>

    <p>
      <label for="spinner">How much do you love science? (optional)</label>
      <input id="spinner" name="spinner">    
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
    </p>
      <p>
      <label for="aoi">Area of Interest (optional)</label>
      <input id="aoi" type="text" name="aoi">
    </p>
      <p>
      <label for="currprobs">Current Problems (optional)</label>
      <input id="currprobs" type="text" name="currprobs">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="launch" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
    <div id="results"></div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#commentForm").submit(function(event){

        /*
        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        };
        */
        alert("SUCCESS?");
    });


});
```

PHP code to return a div after the user has been validated:

```
<?php 

$username = isset($_POST['name'])? trim($_POST['name']):'';
$email= isset($_POST['email'])? trim($_POST['email']):'';

echo '<div id=dynamicDiv>
    <p>Hello, '.$username.'!</p>
    <p>We look forward to contacting you at, '.$email.'</p>
 </div>';
?>
```

## Feedback

Any thoughts are appreciated, even intellectual conversation. Code snippets are idea, but I appreciate anything the community is able

## Edit 1

I motified the javascript and php to reflect knowledgable input and best practice for PHP and AJAX calls, however the issue still remains.

## Edit 2

My goal now is to just get an alert() statement working inside of my javascript, ajax will be the next step.

Comment: You can simply do `data: $(this).serialize()` to pass all your form data. Also, there is no `encode` option.

Comment: Is encode just a feature for like passing `json` objects? So that was just additional information I put into it?

Comment: The problem you describe is usually caused by not including `event.preventDefault();`, but you have that and [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/peqirab/1/edit?html,js,output) using your code. My best guess is that when you created your [mcve] you left out something which is breaking the JS and preventing the `event.preventDefault();` line from being reached.

Comment: @Quentin: I will update my code again, I thought an HTML form with the javascript and PHP files would be enough, but I don't know how to make it more simple without reducing my problem. So I can't even get the form to alert success to the screen, let alone make a ajax call. Do you have any idea what this could be?

Comment: so... you've read those two links, and haven't implemented them in any way shape or form? ***...***

Comment: @Kevin B: Ah, I am experiencing some issues in my javascript console, it seems that an error is popping up crashing javascript after I submit because  `validate() is not a function`. Do I need to manually download this library and put it with my `.html` files?

Comment: @bmc — Your code never tries to call `validate` so if you get that error, it isn't with the code in your question. You need to provide a real [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is here

```
 $("#results").html = html_i;
```

You try change to

```
 $("#results").html(html_i);
```

And in php you should check name and email

```
$username = isset($_POST['name'])? trim($_POST['name']):'';
$email= isset($_POST['email'])? trim($_POST['email']):'';
```

Comment: There still seems to be an issue. My page refreshes with the following target search bar in the browser updated: `http://cs.iupui.edu/~bmconrad/n341/html/resource_center.html?spinner=4&name=Blake&email=bmc.cs%40outlook.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com&aoi=Data+Science&currprobs=34r2r2&comment=%6034t3t` that seemed to store my variables, but it definitely refreshed, which kind of defeats the point of my ajax call. I am updating my code in the question to better reflect my current state.

Comment: @bmc you call `prevenDefault()` to late , move it to the beginning and try again

Comment: @ThanhTùng — It isn't "too late". It can be called any time before the function returns.

Comment: @Quentin i mean... if you call it too late, it may occur after an error has stopped the function from running, thus preventing it from preventing the default action. :p

Answer (score -2):

You should change input type="submit" to input type="button" and call Ajax on onclick function, Its resolve your problem because submit button submit form and Ajax call pending not reached to 400 state.

Comment: except... that removes functionality. You can no longer trigger the submit by pressing enter.